# continuous and covering map

Tags: general-topology

> Let $p:E\rightarrow B$ be a covering map. Let $Y$ be locally path-connected.
>   Let $g:Y\rightarrow E$ be a function (which we do not assume continuous) such that $p\circ g$ is continuous, and $g\circ \gamma$ is continuous for every path $\gamma$ in $Y$. Prove that $g$ is continuous.

Could any one give some hints?

Answer (score 0):

Since $p \circ g$  is continuous, let U be open . Then $(p \circ g) ^{-1}(U)= g^{-1} \circ p^{-1}(U)$ is open . But , since p is continuous , $$p^{-1}(U):=V $$ is open. Then $g^{-1}(V):=W$ is open. Use that p is a local homeomorphism $(p^{-1}p(V)=V)$, etc.
to complete the proof.

Comment: How is the assumption about continuous paths used ?

Comment: @Rene Schipperus: I am waiting for input from the OP to see how to use it.

Comment: $p^{-1}(U)$ is a disjoint union of sets  each homeomorphic to $U$. The path continuity ensures that the image of $Y$ in a nbd of a point lies in one of these sets.

Comment: Thanks ;I meant I wanted to "personalize" the answer depending on the knowledge/doubts in a follow; I try to give a partial answer and then answer followups.

Comment: I see that p is an homeomorphism between V, because $p$ is a covering map hence it is evenly covered. Then $g^{-1}\circ p^{-1}\circ p(V)=g^{-1}(V)$ is open. locally path connected seems have not been used....

Comment: I am sorry, I have to go for a few hours;will be back then.

Comment: @user99680 did you come back?

Comment: @Claire yes, sorry for the delay.Let me continue.